# How to generate unordered list from XML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> Scenario

I am trying to parse an XML file using jQuery to generate an unordered list, but am not able to get the expected output. Please point out the proper way to parse XML using jQuery.

> jsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/wa0znz27/

> Expected output

```
<ul>
    <li>chapter 1</li>
    <li>chapter 2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>lesson 1</li>
        <li>lesson 2</li>
        <li>lesson 3</li>
    </ul>
    <li>chapter 3</li>
        <ul>
            <li>lesson 1</li>
            <ul>
                <li>page 1</li>
                <li>page 2</li>
                <li>page 3</li>
            </ul>
            <li>lesson 2</li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

> Actual output

```
<ul>
    <ul>
        <li>chapter 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>chapter 2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>lesson 1</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>lesson 2</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>lesson 3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>chapter 3</li>
        <ul>
            <li>lesson 1</li>
            <ul>
                <li>page 1</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>page 2</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>page 3</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>lesson 2</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

> Source files

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>var moduleType = "xml";</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="menu"></div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function loadXML(){
    console.log("loading XML");
     parser = new DOMParser();

    //Create a jQuery object
    var xml_text = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?> <course> <name>Multi Level XML &amp; JSON parsing using Javascript</name> <chapter> <id>1</id> <title>Chapter 1</title> <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#chapter-1</url> </chapter> <chapter> <id>2</id> <title>Chapter 2</title> <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#chapter-2</url> <lesson> <id>1</id> <title>Lesson 1</title> <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#lesson-1</url> </lesson> <lesson> <id>2</id> <title>Lesson 2</title> <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#lesson-2</url> </lesson> <lesson> <id>3</id> <title>Lesson 3</title> <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#lesson-3</url> </lesson> </chapter> <chapter> <id>3</id> <title>Chapter 3</title> <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#chapter-3</url> <lesson> <id>1</id> <title>Lesson 1</title> <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#lesson-1-1</url> <page> <id>1</id> <title>Page 1</title> <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#page-1</url> </page> <page> <id>2</id> <title>Page 2</title> <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#page-2</url> </page> <page> <id>3</id> <title>Page 3</title> <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#page-3</url> </page> </lesson> <lesson> <id>2</id> <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#lesson-2-1</url> <title>Lesson 2</title> </lesson> </chapter> </course>";
    var xml = parser.parseFromString(xml_text,"text/xml");
    var course = xml.getElementsByTagName("course");
    $xmlObject = $(xml);

    //load menu
    console.log($xmlObject.find('page').first().find('title').text());
    var $ul = loadMenu($(xml));

    //remove empty ul
    $ul.find('ul').each(function(){
        if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
             $(this).remove();
        }
    });

    //append to menu
    $("#menu").append($ul);
}

function loadMenu($xml){
    var $ul = $("<ul>"); // For each Parent, create an <ul>
    $xml.contents().each(function (index, object) {
        if (object.nodeType == 3) return true;
        if (object.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "TITLE") {
           $("<li>").text($(object).text()).appendTo($ul); // Append <li> Children
        } else {
           $ul.append(loadMenu($(object))); // Recursively append the other Parent
        }
    });
    return $ul;
}




//Load XML
loadXML();
```

XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<course>
    <name>Multi Level XML &amp; JSON parsing using Javascript</name>
    <chapter>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Chapter 1</title>
        <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#chapter-1</url>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>Chapter 2</title>
        <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#chapter-2</url>
        <lesson>
            <id>1</id>
            <title>Lesson 1</title>
            <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#lesson-1</url>
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            <id>2</id>
            <title>Lesson 2</title>
            <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#lesson-2</url>
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            <id>3</id>
            <title>Lesson 3</title>
            <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#lesson-3</url>
        </lesson>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <id>3</id>
        <title>Chapter 3</title>
        <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#chapter-3</url>
        <lesson>
            <id>1</id>
            <title>Lesson 1</title>
            <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#lesson-1-1</url>
            <page>
                <id>1</id>
                <title>Page 1</title>
                <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#page-1</url>
            </page>
            <page>
                <id>2</id>
                <title>Page 2</title>
                <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#page-2</url>
            </page>
            <page>
                <id>3</id>
                <title>Page 3</title>
                <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#page-3</url>
            </page>
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            <id>2</id>
            <url>https://gist.github.com/abhi9bakshi/6e742da5735c1b734eaace452bd45db1#lesson-2-1</url>
            <title>Lesson 2</title>
        </lesson>
    </chapter>
</course>
```

Comment: [`ul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)  can only have `li`as immediate child. _zero or more `<li>` elements, which in turn often contain nested `<ol>` or `<ul>` elements._ So your expected HTML is invalid

Answer (score 0):

The method `$.parseXML` is used to convert a string containing valid XML markup into a standard HTML element tree. [Here is the link to the documentation on this function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

In your case, you would want to either construct the XML as a string, or ingest it through an AJAX call, then pass that string to `$.parseXML`.